Symfony Admin UI with Sonata cross classes relationship error
I've created a **menu option in Sonata Admin. **
Being new to Symfony somehow I tried to show 3 different classes  listed in the left menu.
Finally I've created the new menu items with
php bin/console make:sonata:admin following the 5 steps, entering class Model and so on.
The behavior is that the 3 new options had the same base class classA on list.
When entering +Add new option I managed to add a new record with fields from classB on form, but, guess what, the new record does not show in the list. The same behavior is when adding record from classC. Surely, adding record from classA will show on all the 3 lists :)
In background,  mysql DB, the new record is added properly in the right class associated table, classB, or classC or classA as intended. So, not being present in list for classA now make sense, but why the list is from classA always?
Always I am seeing in all 3 menu options only records from one class, classA, no matter if I am in the menu option that must list classB or classC.
They are different classes, no inheritance, only that they have ManyToOne relationships.
What can be wrong? And why the list is different from create? If the list is from classA, why create is using classB?
I have an empty controller and empty repositories for all the classes. I am planning to add functions but , on this step, I am somehow blocked.
I tried to change class parameter in config/services.yaml but no results. The model classes present here are classA, classB and classC as I intended.
I also tried with composer dump-autoload, and of course some cache clear, even clearing with metadata paramater. Somehow it's stucked in listing the same classA.
Thanks!
